# Use IEnumerable<Enum> in JSON

Tags: json, enums, ienumerable

I have a Enum that goes like this

```
public enum MyEnum: smallint
{
 [Description("Prop1")] Prop1= 0,
 [Description("Prop2")] Prop2= 1,
 [Description("Prop3")] Prop3= 2,
 [Description("Prop4")] Prop4= 3
}
```

Where I used it in my class as:

```
public IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum {get;set}
```

I tried this in my Json Body to pass a value to `myEnum`:

```
{
 "myEnum":[
        {
            "MyEnum":"1"
        },
        {
            "MyEnum":"2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know it is wrong because it shows an error:
"`Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Nullable 1 . . . .` "

I want to know how can I pass a value to my `myEnum` thru JSON. TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you work with C#, maybe this is what you need.
If it is, we can set mark as duplicated.
[Json serialization of enum as string](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net/&ved=2ahUKEwiVksae9svoAhWa-mEKHZyOC3UQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2MRlzgxPqJmFkuKRCuAXVb&cshid=1585905470823)